# Python, A simple sum list with combination in index

Tags: python, list

I have the following list

```
Values=[ 0 , 1 , 2 ]
```

My aim is to produce the following

```
MySums=[1+2,0+2,0+1]
```

Is there a built in function for combinations ?

Comment: ty to all for your answers!!

Comment: It is considered good etiquette to accept the answer that was the most satisfactory. I'm not saying this to get you to accept mine, it doesn't matter, just accept one. People will eventually not bother to answer your questions if you don't accept any answers.

Answer (score 5):

Yup, you can use [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
import itertools

In [6]: values = [0, 1, 2]

In [7]: list(itertools.combinations(values, 2))
Out[7]: [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
```

If you want to sum them:

```
In [9]: list(sum(x) for x in itertools.combinations(values, 2))
Out[9]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> Values=[ 0 , 1 , 2 ]
```

You can use `itertools.combinations`

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> list(combinations(Values, r=2))
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
```

I thought you might want this

```
>>> [x + y for x, y in combinations(Values, r=2)]
[1, 2, 3]
```

But it appears you want it backwards:

```
>>> [x + y for x, y in combinations(reversed(Values), r=2)]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
>>> values=[ 0 , 1 , 2 ]
>>> [ sum(list(i)) for i in itertools.combinations(values,2)]
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take a look at [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) , and more specifically [`itertools.combinations()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).